# How to find the derivative of $e_iAe_j^T$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

$A\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times q}$ and $e_i, e_j$ are unit vectors.

How can I find $(e_iAe_j^T)'$?

Let $A$ be the i.e. Jacobi Matrix. Differentiation wrt a variable $x_k$.

Comment: I do not understand the question: we are differentiating with respect to which variable? In other terms: is $A$ depending on $t$ or $e_i,e_j$ depending on $t$? Maybe both?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming $e_i$ is a row vector and $e_j$ is a column vector. Then you can write $e_i A e_j$ as a sum, and apply linearity of $\frac{d}{dx}$.

For example, if $e_i$ is the standard basis vector with a $1$ in the $i$th entry (and $0$ everywhere else), and $e_j$ is the standard basis vector with a $1$ in the $j$th entry (and $0$ everywhere else), then

$$\frac{d}{dx} e_i A e_j =
\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^n e_k A_{k,l}e_l = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^n \frac{d}{dx}e_k A_{k,l}e_l = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^n e_k A_{k,l}'e_l,
$$
and if I assumed correctly about $e_i$ and $e_j$, then the terms in the last double-sum are $0$ for $k \neq l \neq i \neq j$, so
$$\frac{d}{dx} e_i A e_j =e_i A'_{i,j}e_j.
$$
If I didn't assume correctly about $e_i$ and $e_j$, then
$$ \frac{d}{dx} e_i A e_j = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^n \frac{d}{dx}e_k A_{k,l}e_l$$
still applies, and you can figure it out yourself from there.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: I have edited the answer to make it obvious.